# OAuth2 SSO with User Roles and Permissions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am going to deploy a small spring boot application on a server running on my company network. Its a Spring boot application and i need to implement the Authentication/Authorization using an existing OAtuh2 authentication server .

Now the requirement says:  If i am already logged in to my network, it should do an SSO sign-in to the application using a token from existing oAuth server that is being used. If not logged into the network,  it should not allow me to get to the application.

Also I  wanted to know if i can extract various roles and permissions associated with a user from an oAuth2 token as i need to populate data based on user Permissions . Is this possible to extract this info from an oAuth token or  Is this possible  only possible via a JWT token?  Which will be the best approach to solve this?

Comment: Can you tell us which authorization flow the application should use?

Comment: If your token does not contain roles and permissions, is it possible to get this information from the authentication service?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2-boot-resource-server-user-info